# How to push array elements as each in nested array in mongodb using nodejs

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

I want to push the array elements as each in nested array in mongodb the code that i am using is this:

```
$push:{
    "websites.$.ads":{
        "ad_type":{"$each":["320x40","480x30"]}
    }
}
```

I have the following schema design:

```
_id:KLNkl23klmKLM233mKLM233
websites:[     
    {  
        _id:"xyz"  
        ads:[ 
            ad_type:""  
        ]   
    },
    {  
        _id:"xyz"  
        ads:[ 
            ad_type:""  
        ]   
    }
]
```

**What i want to get at the end is**

```
{   
  "_id" : ObjectId("some id"),   
  "websites" : [  
             { 
                 "ads" : [ 
                     { _id:"asdfasdf" , "ad_type" : "some value" },
                     { _id:"asdfasdf" , "ad_type" : "some value" },
                     { _id:"asdfasdf" , "ad_type" : "some value" }  
                 ] 
             } 
   ] 
 }
```

Comment: I don't get what do you need at the end. Is it something like{ "_id" : ObjectId("some id"), "websites" : [ { "ads" : [ { "ad_type" : "some value" } ] }, { "ads" : [ { "ad_type" : "some value" } ] } ] }

Comment: I edited the question above please have a look at that i want to achieve that

Answer (score 0):

You can use [positional argument](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/positional-all/) of array update   . I tried below syntax to make it work and the output below

```
db.coll.update({}, {
    $push: {
        'websites.$[].ads': {
            $each: [{
                    _id: 'some_id',
                    ad_type: 'some value'
                }
            ]
        }
    }
})
```

**OUTPUT**

```
{
        "_id": ObjectId("SOME_MAIN_ID"),
        "websites": [{
                "ads": [{
                        "_id": "some_id",
                        "ad_type": "some value"
                    }, {
                        "_id": "some_id_1",
                        "ad_type": "some value_1"
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
```

**EDITED For changing arrays**

```
db.coll.update({}, {
    $set: {
        'websites.$[].ads': [{
                _id: 'some_id_1',
                ad_type: 'some value_1'
            }
        ]
    }
})
WriteResult({
    "nMatched": 1,
    "nUpserted": 0,
    "nModified": 1
})
db.coll.find() {
    "_id": 'SOME_MAIN_ID',
    "websites": [{
            "ads": [{
                    "_id": "some_id_1",
                    "ad_type": "some value_1"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
db.coll.update({}, {
    $set: {
        ' websites.$[].ads ': [{
                _id: ' some_id_1 ',
                ad_type: ' some value_1 '
            }, {
                _id: ' some_other_id_2 ',
                ad_type: ' some_other_type '
            }
        ]
    }
})

WriteResult({
    "nMatched": 1,
    "nUpserted": 0,
    "nModified": 1
})
db.coll.find() {
    "_id": 'SOME_MAIN_ID',
    "websites": [{
            "ads": [{
                    "_id": "some_id_1",
                    "ad_type": "some value_1"
                }, {
                    "_id": "some_other_id_2",
                    "ad_type": "some_other_type"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer but Let suppose i have a dynamic array that is changing every time e.g ["someValue","someValue","someValue"] these all are refered to as ad_types now i want to push each of these to get the output above how can i do that

Comment: Yes Like ["320x50","video-impressions","720x80"] and so on

Comment: I think this can be achived with $each but don't know how

Comment: Well, in that case you have 2 options, either you find first what has been changed and then push into mongodb else as it is ever changing and it could be difficult at times to find what changed, then set the complete array in mongodb, updated the answer

Comment: I appreciate and Thanks for your answer but this is not what i am looking for actually i am writing a nodejs app in which user will enter the ad name that he wants it could be 1 2 3 and so on what i am doing is getting all names in array and want to push at once by using $each without checking that it already exists in array or not currently i am achieving this by using forEach loop and pushing one by one value in the ads array in mongodb but this is bad idea

Comment: That is what i am saying, you don't need to write a foreach loop on array, you just set the array in mongodb after user selection or enter is over